# PayPal Payment Excute Error: Method type not supported for this operation

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When we try to complete a PayPal payment we're getting an error.

Curl URL

> https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6919774712486433JLP6PPIQ/excute/

```
HTTP Headers
Content-Type: application\/json","Authorization: Bearer A21AAHreFxxtc86Y_27nsOJp9e"

Data
{"payer_id":"LUQRF5YkjhXG6"}

Error
{
    "name": "MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "message": "Method type not supported for this operation",
    "information_link": "https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/webapps\/developer\/docs\/api\/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "debug_id": "dd9ba4864e05c"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PayPal Classic API TransactionSearch method not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519945/paypal-classic-api-transactionsearch-method-not-supported)

Comment: Never give out sensitive information such as your access token or the payer ID on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your URL

It should be `execute` not `excute`.

Use: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6919774712486433JLP6PPIQ/execute/

Comment: Well spotted, typos are really a pain at times!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!